# How to display the facebook details automatically in android app as long as there is an active access token?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm creating an android application in which i am using facebook login.I'm using graph api for this purpose.I want to display the profile picture,name and location of the logged-in user.I have a method for getting the profile information.I want to display the details each time i open my app without calling the login method each time.ie.i want to display the details automatically as long as there is an active access token.How to do this ?

My method for login is working fine.How to display the details automatically as long as there is an active access token ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Session object to create a new Session using your Facebook access token, and token expiry date

Answer (score 0):

You can store user info in [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

for example; You can save user data after login

```
// this Application Context  
   SharedPreferences preferences  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);      
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

   editor.putString("name",retrievedName);

   editor.putString("picture",retrievedPicture);

   editor.putString("location",retrivedLocation);

   editor.commit();
```

Then you can check easily if user authenticated
[getString(String key, String defValue)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
 //if it is null login again
 String name = preferences.getString("name",null);
```

Or you can use sqlite as well but if you are developing native app it would be better to use [facebook android sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)

Comment: if you mean showing picture there are a lot of ways to do that such as these libraries 'universal image loader', http://square.github.io/picasso/ but you can still load it with AsyncTask see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212463/android-imageview-load-image-from-url